# How to create a (multi-field) search form in MS Access with MySQL Backend?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I'm creating an Access form frontend for a MySQL backend, and I'm wondering if there's a way to create a search form for a table that searches multiple fields. When looking for answers on this topic, the consensus I seem to find is "Learn and use VBA", but I'm wondering if that still applies when using a MySQL backend. Since I'm relatively well-versed in MySQL, whipping up a query to search multiple fields is trivial, but I don't know how I can incorporate this in Access. Does anyone have experience with this that can help?

Comment: Yes, VBA will still be the primary method for automating the behaviour of your Access forms. That holds true regardless of the back-end your Access application uses. In some cases your MySQL skills may come in handy if you want to use a pass-through query to send an SQL statement directly to the MySQL back-end, but most of the time your Access application will be communicating with MySQL on your behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the least amount of work, and best  choice is simply to toss up a form, let the  user enter the values to search for, and then pass a "where" clause to the form or report that you want to filter.

Access does the above rather well, and will ONLY pull down the records that meet the critera.

so say to search for a customer, you toss up a form like this:

[image]

So, in above, the user typed in Smi.

So, our code can go:

me.RecordSource = "select * from tblCustomers where LastName like '" & me.txtSearch & "*'"

Now, in that case we did create SQL. But you could also go:

```
docmd.OpenReport "rptCustomers",,,"LastName like '" & me.txtSearch & "*'"
```

So, passing a where clause to a form will eliminate the need to write or concatenate sql strings.

Once you display the results, then you can as aobve shows a drill down. When you click on a single row in above (glasses icon), then we launch the form to the one record with  this:

docmd.OpenReport "ViewTour",,,"id = " & me!id

So, in most cases, by using the "where" clause, then you don't have to create or write SQL queries.

And if your form is simply say name, and a optional city?

```
dim strWhere   as string

if isnull(me.LastName) = False then
   strWhere = "LastName = '" & me.LastName & "'"
End if

If isnull(me.City) = False then
    if strWhere <> "" then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
    strWhere = strWhere & "City = '" & me.City & "'"
end if

' as many more "optional" text boxes on the search form can follow
' if you leave the box blank, then the critera is not added.
```